# What are hyperfunctions in the context of computer science?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, arrows

In [Arrows: A General Interface to Computation](https://www.haskell.org/arrows/) I found this brief remark on hyperfunctions:

> The weird datatype
>
> ```
> newtype Hyper b c = H (Hyper c b -> c)
> ```
>
> can be shown to be an arrow [KLP01].

but the link to the paper is broken.

There is also [hyperfunctions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hyperfunctions-0/docs/Control-Monad-Hyper.html) package on Hackage.

Neither provides any explanation of what they are and what are their properties.

So what are hyperfunctions, how are they useful and what are their properties?

---

<sup>Apparently the same name is used for something completely different [in the context of holomorphic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfunction)</sup>

<sup>As I know almost nothing about the concept, I just guessed the tags from my current references coming from Haskell/FP, feel free to correct them.</sup>

Comment: Here's a working link to the cited paper: http://www.csee.ogi.edu/~krstics/psfiles/hyperfunctions.pdf from here http://www.csee.ogi.edu/~krstics/

Comment: Plus [another one](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5135.pdf) in Haskell context.

Answer (score 7):

I could find something here: http://www.citeulike.org/user/Benja/author/Launchbury:J

> Abstract
>   Hyperfunctions from `A` to `B` are elements of the infinitely
>   nested function type
>
> ```
> [A; B] = (((...) -> A) -> B) -> A) -> B: ...
> ```

Comment: "innitely" adv. - The result of copy&pasting the word "infinitely" from a PDF which used a ligature to represent "fi", when the copy machinery did not know how to translate it back into characters. ;-)

Comment: "I could find something here"
Now that link is dead too :( the internet is a dying place.